# The greatest lower bound of $\{\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\}\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

I have definition:

[image]

I think the answer is $\{3;4\}$. It's  a correct?

Comment: @coffeemath: Of course it is a poset. _Every_ set of sets ordered by $\subseteq$ makes a poset.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're right! Deleting comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your answer is indeed correct.